# How can I Display Object PHP

Tags: php

I have code like this :

```
$dataRecord1 = $client->GetRecord($token, $table, $filter);
echo "<pre>"; print_r($dataRecord1); echo "</pre>"; 
foreach ($dataRecord1->result as $drm) {
    echo "<tr><td>$drm->id</td>
              <td>$drm->nm</td>
          </tr>";
}
```

if i use print_r($dataRecord1) will display like this :

```
stdClass Object
(
    [error_code] => 0
    [error_desc] => 
    [result] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [nm] => Josh
        )

)
```

but if with foreach doesn't display anything. I want display like this :

```
----------------
| id  |  nm    |
----------------
| 1   | Josh   |
----------------
```

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: you are fetching an object not an array. Write a getter method, and get array with the same data ... and foreach shall work

Answer (score 1):

why do you foreach $dataRecord1->result? That is not an array, that is another object. Try

```
echo $dataRecord1->result->id; 
echo $dataRecord1->result->nm;
```

Comment: @FebryDamatrasetaFairuz It doesn't matter if it's one or more just like it wouldn't matter for the array if it's one or more. If you see "Object" you need to use -> , not []. For the main stdClass Object you still have more children then "result" ("error_code", "error_desc"), and taking data through $dataRecord1->result worked, right? ;)

Answer (score 0):

`$dataRecord1->result` is not an array. The `foreach` is basically iterating on the properties of your object `$dataRecord1->result`.

So, you can just remove the foreach, like that :

```
$dataRecord1 = $client->GetRecord($token, $table, $filter);
echo "<pre>"; print_r($dataRecord1); echo "</pre>"; 
echo "<tr><td>" . $dataRecord1->result->id . "</td><td>" . $dataRecord1->result->nm . "</td></tr>";
```

Or if you really want to use a foreach :

```
$dataRecord1 = $client->GetRecord($token, $table, $filter);
echo "<pre>"; print_r($dataRecord1); echo "</pre>"; 
echo "<tr>";
foreach ($dataRecord1->result as $k => $v) 
{ 
      echo '<td>' . $v . '</td>';
}
echo '</tr>';
```

You will also need to add code to display the table header.

Comment: if i use     echo "<tr><td>$dataRecord1->result->id</td><td>$dataRecord1->result->nm</td></tr>";    doesn't display anything. But if I use foreach ($dataRecord1->result as $k => $v) it's working. Thx..

Comment: Indeed, I corrected the code. Just need to have `$dataRecord1->result->id` outside of the `"`